# An inequality for matrix

Tags: matrices, inequality

$A$, $B$ are Hermitian matrix, how to show
$$|\operatorname{trace}(e^A)|\geq|\operatorname{trace}(e^{A+iB})|$$
As a special case, if A is zero, then the inequality is reduced to $n\geq \operatorname{trace}(U)$, where $U$ is a unitary matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known result. See Corollary 6 of

> D. Petz, [A survey of trace inequalities](http://www.renyi.hu/%7Epetz/pdf/64.pdf), *Functional Analysis and Operator Theory*, 287–298, Banach Center Publications, 30 (Warszawa 1994).